# How can I set the value of an input within a DIV class?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<td class="ui-widget-content" style="width: 244px;">
   <span id="refLink_9" class="refLink">
      <input type="text" value="/C02E/Java-Notes-Classes1" size="30" name="item.Link" id="Link_9" 
         class="wijmo-wijtextbox ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">24</input>
   </span>
</td>
```

I tried to set the value of the input as follows. But it's not working.

```
var linkValue = 25;
$(".refLink input").html(linkValue);
```

Can anyone point me to what's wrong?

Comment: Further to the provided answers you're using the `input` tag wrong: there's no `</input>` closing tag, the `input` is a self-closing empty tag: `<input <!-- other attributes --> value="whatever" />`, and the contents of the `value` attribute will pre-fill the tag itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`.val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) not [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html):

```
var linkValue = 25;
$(".refLink input").val(linkValue);
```

`.val` is for setting the *value* of each element (typically used for form fields), and `.html` is used to set the html *content* of each element.

Also, per @DavidThomas' comment above, your input should look more like this:

```
<input type="text" value="/C02E/Java-Notes-Classes1" size="30" name="item.Link" id="Link_9" 
     class="wijmo-wijtextbox ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" value="24" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `.val()`:

```
$(".refLink input").val(linkValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with:

```
<input type="text" value="/C02E/Java-Notes-Classes1" size="30" name="item.Link" id="Link_9" class="wijmo-wijtextbox ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">24</input>
```

is not standard practice. `Input` isn't meant to have an end tag and so the value of a `textbox` is provided via it's `value` attribute. Thus, the `textbox` will be set to */C02E/Java-Notes-Classes1* while *24* will just be plain text.

Answering your question, using

```
$(".refLink input").val(linkValue);
```

will allow you to set the value of the `textbox`, thus essentially over-writting */C02E/Java-Notes-Classes1* rather than *24* which I'm assuming you expect as the behaviour.